# .Net MVC Radar Chart Polygon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mschart

I'm trying to create a radar chart with the drawing style as polygon instead of circle in the MVC chart helper but i cannot find the AreaDrawingStyle anywhere in it.

I know in the regular ASP chart control i can do:

```
chart1.Series["Default"]["AreaDrawingStyle"] = "Polygon";
```

But in my MVC code, i have:

```
Chart myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddTitle("Chart Title")
            .AddSeries(
                name: "Employee",
                chartType: "Radar",
                xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
                yValues: new[] { "20", "60", "41", "55", "33" });
```

Does anyone know where to find it? I searched lots of places but i am having a hard time finding specific details about this particular type of chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to make my MVC chart use polygon as well.  This link helped me a lot by allowing me to style the chart using the underlying System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting classes:
http://truncatedcodr.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/system-web-helpers-chart-custom-themes/

In short, try this nasty stuff...

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea ca = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea("Default");

var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
chart.Series.Add("MySeries");
chart.Series["MySeries"]["AreaDrawingStyle"] = "Polygon";

var cs = chart.Serializer;
cs.IsTemplateMode = true;
cs.Format = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SerializationFormat.Xml;
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
using ( System.Xml.XmlWriter xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    cs.Save(xw);
}
string theme = sb.ToString().Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");

System.Web.Helpers.Chart myChart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 1024, height: 768, theme:theme);
```

And now you have a whole new name space to look into for formatting your charts!